# MessageBox In GTK Never Shown

Tags: c#, gtk

I am using VS Code on OSX and am trying to on my button press event, display a dialog to user.  The code below is what I have, but when the button is pressed, the dialog is never shown.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Init();

        MainWindow win = new MainWindow();

        Button btnClick = new Button("Button");
        win.Add(btnClick);

        btnClick.ButtonPressEvent += new ButtonPressEventHandler(ButtonPressHandler);
        btnClick.Visible = true;
        win.Show();
        Application.Run();

    }

    private static void ButtonPressHandler(object obj, ButtonPressEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(null, DialogFlags.DestroyWithParent, MessageType.Error, ButtonsType.Ok, "You pressed the button!");
        md.Run();
        md.Destroy();
    }
```

Comment: Minimal Working Example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want btnClick.Clicked rather than btnClick.ButtonPressEvent. There doesn't even seem to be a ButtonPressEvent member. See http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.Button